# Android NDK crash in /system/lib/libz.so

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm running a Cocos2dx project and I'm getting seemingly random crashes happening on Android. I am testing on a Samsung Galaxy Note, however I was able to get the same crash on other Android devices too.

The crash happened when I tried to read from a zip file (expansion file). The likelihood of the game crashing is around 1%, so I don't have definitive repro steps.

Here's the stack trace:

```
F/libc    (11564): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000003 (code=1), thread 11592 (Thread-866)
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/GT-N7000/GT-N7000:4.1.2/JZO54K/N7000XXLT9:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): pid: 11564, tid: 11592, name: Thread-866  >>> com.example.myapp <<<
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000003
V/AlarmManager( 2007): waitForAlarm result :2
D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController( 2129): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
W/AlarmManager( 2007): FACTORY_ON= 0
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     r0 0005ffff  r1 5fb96b58  r2 00000004  r3 ffffffff
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     r4 000004e0  r5 5fbc8180  r6 00000038  r7 80000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     r8 00000000  r9 5e314f3c  sl 5e301420  fp 5e41494c
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     ip ffffffff  sp 5e4148c0  lr 4004c013  pc 4004c538  cpsr a0000030
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     d6  0000020000000000  d7  3f80000044000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     d16 0000000000000000  d17 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     scr 20000011
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     #00  pc 00014538  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+1371)
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     #01  pc 00016f7f  /system/lib/libc.so (malloc+10)
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     #02  pc 00bf49b4  /data/data/com.example.myapp/lib/libgame.so (operator new(unsigned int)+24)
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): stack:
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e414880  fffffff1  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e414884  40110dc4  /system/lib/libz.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e414888  5e314f44  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e41488c  5e414c80  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e414890  5ed8356c  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e414894  fffffff1  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e414898  5ed47448  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e41489c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e4148a0  5e414c80  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e4148a4  4010b7c0  /system/lib/libz.so (inflateInit2_+136)
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e4148a8  c0000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e4148ac  000004d9  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e4148b0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e4148b4  002fd0d0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e4148b8  df0027ad  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e4148bc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     #00  5e4148c0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e4148c4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e4148c8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e4148cc  5ea2ef50  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e4148d0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e4148d4  000004d9  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e4148d8  5f0a2dfc  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e4148dc  002fd0d0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e4148e0  5e314f44  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e4148e4  5e414c80  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e4148e8  5e314f3c  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e4148ec  5e301420  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e4148f0  5e41494c  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e4148f4  4004ef81  /system/lib/libc.so (malloc+12)
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     #01  5e4148f8  000004d9  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e4148fc  5dcfd9b8  /data/data/com.example.myapp/lib/libgame.so (operator new(unsigned int)+28)
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     #02  5e414900  5ea2df18  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e414904  5f0a2dfc  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e414908  5ecef9a4  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e41490c  5dcfccf4  /data/data/com.example.myapp/lib/libgame.so (operator new[](unsigned int)+8)
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e414910  000004d9  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e414914  5db3e3e8  /data/data/com.example.myapp/lib/libgame.so (cocos2d::ZipFile::getFileData(std::string const&, unsigned long*)+352)
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e414918  5f0a2e22  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e41491c  5e414998  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e414920  5e414968  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e414924  5ea2df18  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e414928  5fc75108  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e41492c  5ea2df30  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e414930  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e414934  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e414938  5e414984  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):          5e41493c  01d971d9  
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): memory near r0:
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     0005ffdc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     0005ffec ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     0005fffc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     0006000c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     0006001c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): memory near r1:
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5fb96b38 00000000 00000000 00000000 ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5fb96b48 00000000 00000000 40c19600 5edf1128  ...........@(..^
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5fb96b58 000000a8 000005e1 5fb96b58 5fb96b58  ........Xk._Xk._
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5fb96b68 5fb94fd8 5eceb800 5fbc8180 00000004  .O._...^..._....
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5fb96b78 00000000 3f800000 3f800000 00000000  .......?...?....
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): memory near r5:
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5fbc8160 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5fbc8170 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5fbc8180 00630061 00000519 5fbc8180 5fbc8180  a.c........_..._
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5fbc8190 5fb8ee78 5fb96b58 4008163c 00000004  x.._Xk._<..@....
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5fbc81a0 00000000 3f800000 3f800000 00000000  .......?...?....
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): memory near r7:
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     7fffffe0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     7ffffff0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     80000000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     80000010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     80000020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): memory near r9:
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5e314f1c 00000000 00000000 5f53b6e9 5e314f50  ..........S_PO1^
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5e314f2c 5d0620a0 5745d968 00000000 00000000  . .]h.EW........
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5e314f3c 5e314f6c 588d8406 5745dcf0 5d0620a0  lO1^...X..EW. .]
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5e314f4c 5f540e05 42150c40 421f3670 5e314fdc  ..T_@..Bp6.B.O1^
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5e314f5c 588d8a00 5745e4d8 588d8406 00000000  ...X..EW...X....
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): memory near sl:
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5e301400 3f800000 00000010 41476e00 00000453  ...?.....nGAS...
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5e301410 5d0620a0 5e314f3c 5745dcf0 5cff9000  . .]<O1^..EW...\
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5e301420 421c9308 00000000 5e414da8 00000000  ...B.....MA^....
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5e301430 5e414ddc 0000000b 00000000 408220c0  .MA^......... .@
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5e301440 00000000 00000000 566e8270 5e311300  ........p.nV..1^
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): memory near fp:
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5e41492c 5ea2df30 00000000 00000000 5e414984  0..^.........IA^
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5e41493c 01d971d9 000000ad 000004d9 5e414984  .q...........IA^
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5e41494c 5db1664c 5e414998 5de6a954 5f0a0944  Lf.].IA^T..]D.._
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5e41495c 5ea2cca8 60de10b8 5f0a2dfc 5f0a22ec  ...^...`.-._."._
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5e41496c 00000000 60de10b8 5db0ceec 5db0ceec  .......`...]...]
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): memory near sp:
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5e4148a0 5e414c80 4010b7c0 c0000000 000004d9  .LA^...@........
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5e4148b0 00000000 002fd0d0 df0027ad 00000000  ....../..'......
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5e4148c0 00000000 00000000 00000000 5ea2ef50  ............P..^
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5e4148d0 00000000 000004d9 5f0a2dfc 002fd0d0  .........-._../.
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     5e4148e0 5e314f44 5e414c80 5e314f3c 5e301420  DO1^.LA^<O1^ .0^
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     4004c518 0c82eb05 312cf8dc 0856b38b f1c62a1f  ......,1..V..*..
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     4004c528 bf080719 21002700 f707fa14 460d4646  .....'.!....FF.F
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     4004c538 c004f8d3 0803f02c 0808ebc4 d20445b0  ....,........E..
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     4004c548 0f00f1b8 4646d01b ea4f461d f8d378d7  ......FF.FO..x..
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     4004c558 f108c014 f8530804 f11c3028 bf180800  ......S.(0......
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     4004bff0 b930fd21 2becf8df f8d2447a 078b11b4  !.0....+zD......
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     4004c000 f8dfd50a 447d5be4 70dcf505 f7fe2500  .....[}D...p.%..
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     4004c010 2800e958 8249f041 f2002cf4 2c0a823f  X..(A.I..,..?..,
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     4004c020 340bd903 0407f024 2410e000 7bbcf8df  ...4$......$...{
I/DEBUG   ( 1717):     4004c030 447f08e2 fa36683e 079df302 f003d042  ...D>h6.....B...
I/DEBUG   ( 1717): !@dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_native -m 11564
```

Comment: On the face of it, the crash is in `malloc` which is called from your code `/data/data/com.example.myapp/lib/libgame.so` through `operator new()`.

Comment: Is there a reason why this happens so randomly?

Comment: If something is corrupting the native heap, it won't be noticed until malloc() or free() happens to run into the corrupted section.  This could be right away or could be much later.  Do you see a libc / dlmalloc complaint in the lines right before the crash?

Comment: Nothing unusual other than what was pasted in the original post. I have check JNI enabled and have rectified all warnings raised by diligently deleting local references

Comment: If you have a rooted device, you can try `libc.debug.malloc` (see http://source.android.com/devices/native-memory.html).  There are actually 3 settings (1, 5, 10); try 10 and see if it complains about heap corruption.

Answer (score 0):

The crash is very likely to be because of heap corruption due to leak from improper memory deallocation.

If you are using C++ then I suggest you to use `std::tr1::shared_ptr` to avoid manually freeing memory. If you use C only, then try best not to malloc/free.

It can also be result of `mmap` without `munmap`. `munmap` immediately after you are done with memory allocated by `mmap`.

Comment: This doesn't look like a double-free.  The dlmalloc library knows when memory has been previously been freed and you get a clean error.  It's failing in malloc(), not free(), so this isn't a case of freeing something that isn't a malloc block.